# Setting SetupIconFile to certain icon changes also icon on Destination Location and Start Menu pages

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I would like to know if it is possible to replace, or change, the icon that appears on various pages of Inno Setup install routine (eg: *Select Destination Location*, *Select Start Menu Folder*,...), when using the `SetupIconFile=MyProgSetup.ico` directive.

I am asking this because when using the above directive, the icon displayed in the *Select Destination Location* page is poorly rendered becoming unrecognizable.

Is it possible to use the original image, like not using `SetupIconFile=MyProgSetup.ico` directive?

Below the code snippet.

```
#define MyAppName "My Program"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"
#define MyAppExeName "MyProg.exe"

[Setup]
AppId={{8AAA5113-D0B7-4C6B-84F1-7015709E191C}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
DefaultDirName={autopf}\{#MyAppName}
OutputBaseFilename=mysetup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
SetupIconFile=SetupUnInstall.ico

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Original icon in *Select Destination Location* page with Yellow Folder Icon:

[image]

Next, Same page with `SetupIconFile=MyProgSetup.ico` directive:

[image]

The `MyProgSetup.ico` icon:

[image]

Link to problematic icon file:
[SetupUnInstall.ico](https://mega.nz/file/AioDnTJJ#HwKj0JYkdNXVy9Aycbma6uWUu7f_5KX_78E6Q-4w_ao)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in Inno Setup 6.2 and it has been fixed in 6.2.1:
https://jrsoftware.org/files/is6-whatsnew.htm#6.2.1